# why run setup.py, can I just embed the code?

Tags: python

I am writing a CLI python application that has dependencies on a few libraries (Paramiko etc.).
If I download their source and just place them under my main application source, I can import them and everything works just fine. 
Why would I ever need to run their setup.py installers or deal with python package managers?

I understand that when deploying server side applications it is OK for an admin to run easy_install/pip commands etc to install the prerequsites, but for a script like CLI apps that have to be distributed as a self-contained apps that only depend on a python binary, what is the recommented approach?

Comment: setup.py is the general way that also allows C-compiled packages. But in many cases it does only copying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several reasons:

- Not all packages are pure-python packages. It's easy to include C-extensions in your package and have `setup.py` automate the compilation process.
- Automated dependency management; dependencies are declared and installed for you by the installer tools (`pip`, `easy_install`, `zc.buildout`). Dependencies can be declared dynamically too (try to import `json`, if that fails, declare a dependency on `simplejson`, etc.).
- Custom resource installation setups. The installation process is highly configurable and dynamic. The same goes for dependency detection; the `cx_Oracle` has to jump through quite some hoops to make installation straightforward with all the various platforms and quirks of the Oracle library distribution options it needs to support, for example.

Why would you still want to do this for CLI scripts? That depends on how crucial the CLI is to you; will you be maintaining this over the coming years? Then I'd still use a `setup.py`, because it *documents* what the dependencies are, including minimal version needs. You can add tests (`python setup.py test`), and deploy to new locations or upgrade dependencies with ease.

Comment: The crutial is that it is dead simple to distribute, ideally users shouldn't need to know that python is used at all - The instuctions should be: extract the given .tgz to a directory (assuming a certain Linux distibution, containing certain version of Python) and run <dir>/bin/<commands> from there. If any of the libraries have dependencies,  can I do all the packaging and traversal at build time (assumption is there are no native libraries), and then just distribute a self-contaied archive?

Comment: @Ivan: You can do that, sure, provided your target users have the right python versions installed. But if this is a CLI, how hard is it to run `python setup.py somecommand`?

Comment: Martijn, so you are recommending, say, having a setup.sh that (root) user would have to run first, that would run 'python setup.py install' on each of the libraries used, which would copy them to the machine wide place and do all the required library setup?

Comment: @Ivan: `setup.py` can do in-place installs. You can use a virtualenv. You can use `zc.buildout` (which is what I'd use, more control over where stuff is installed).